# Linux = Bridge with multiple Port behaves as a switch?

Tags: linux, networking

I know how the internal linux bridge works with two ports/interfaces.

But what happens when I have multiple virtual machines on a physical machine hosted, that each are plugged (via tun/tap) into the bridge on the host machine? Does the bridge then automatically behave like a switch? Or do I have to configure something special?

Thanks!!!
Jan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing special.  It behaves like a switch, maintaining an internal list of the MAC addresses visible on each interface and passing the packets accordingly.  It can even do STP.

Comment: "Bridge" and "switch" are usually interchangeable when talking about networking; all switches as one would normally think of them are really multiport bridges.